# On Scheme cons and dots notation

Tags: scheme, cons

Given

```
#;> (cons (cons 1 2) 3)
((1 . 2) . 3)
```

When we try

```
#;> (cons 3 (cons 1 2))
(3 1 . 2)
```

What governs where the `.` is used? What would the memory representation of these constructs be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scheme implementations usually print things that look like lists in list form:

```
-> (cons 1 (cons 2 '()))
'(1 2)
```

In your example, `(cons 3 (cons 1 2))` would be a list if it weren't for the last `2`. So your implementation makes a best effort to print it as a list until the `2`. The other example does not contain any part that looks like a list, so it just prints as nested pairs.